# iPhone screenshot of transformed UIImageView

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiimageview

My problem is this -

I have a UIImageView which a user can rotate freely.

I would now like to be able to capture just this newly rotated image.

The code below, which can take a screenshot of an individual view, unfortunately returns
a screenshot of the view in its unrotated state.

```
-(IBAction)captureScreen:(id)sender
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imgView.frame.size);
    [imgView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenshot, nil, nil, nil);
}
```

Any ideas how can I retain the rotation here?

Comment: can you put the code of rotation what you are implementing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your code on a view containing the rotated view not on the rotated view itself.

Comment: Thanks Simon, this partially works - the problem being that when the imageView is rotated, the containing view doesn't grow to reflect the new frame of the image view, resulting in a cropped screenshot. I feel quite stupid here, because I can't seem to make the containing view match the dimensions of the rotated imageView. I've tried setting the bounds and frame properties of the containing view dynamically as the imageview is rotated - but no joy...?

Comment: I tried by using self.view and still no joy for a zoomed in transformed view http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15574845/how-do-i-take-a-screenshot-of-a-view-which-has-transform I have

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size); 
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);
    NSString *yourPath;
    NSString  *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:yourPath];
    [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(viewImage, 1.0) writeToFile:jpgPath atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are rotating the image through the UIImage methods. Problem with that is that it's not really rotating the image itself, it's just telling whoever draws it to draw it sideways.

I would suggest you just actually rotate the image using core graphics and then you can save the result that way